# I don't know why this R loop code doesn't work

Tags: r, loops, regression

I made loop code for linear regression by two subgroups combination and for two dependent variable.
But it doesn't work with error. 
Is there someone can fix my code?

```r
each_lm <-data.frame(matrix(nrow=1, ncol=10))
names(each_lm)=c("col1", "col2", "col3", "Estimate", " Std. Error", " z value", " pValue", "2.5%", "97.5%","r^2")
e=1
for (i in c("sbp","dbp")) {
  for (j in c("1","2","3","4","5")) {
   for (k in c("2002","2005","2008","2011","2014","2017")){
      form <- formula(paste0(i,"~bmi"))
      result <- lm(form, data=subset(bp, gr_bmi==j & year==k)
      each_lm[e,1]<-i
      each_lm[e,2]<-j
      each_lm[e,3]<-k
      each_lm[e,4]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,1],3)
      each_lm[e,5]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,2],3)
      each_lm[e,6]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,3],3)
      each_lm[e,7]<-round(coef(summary(result))[2,4],3)
      each_lm[e,8]<-round(confint(result)[2,1],2)
      each_lm[e,9]<-round(confint(result)[2,2],2)
      each_lm[e,10]<-round(summary(result)$r.squared, 3)
    e<-e+1
    }
  }
}
write.xlsx(each_lm, "c:/R/sbp_bmi/Table4_2.xlsx")
```

Error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"      result <- lm(form, data=subset(bp, gr_bmi==j & year==k)
      each_lm"
Error: object 'k' not found
Error in round(summary(result)$r.squared, 3) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that one of your functions is not closed properly. In the line:

```r
result <- lm(form, data=subset(bp, gr_bmi==j & year==k)
```

There is only 1 closing bracket, whereas there should be 2, because you are callin 2 functions.

Replacing it with this will fix it

```
result <- lm(form, data=subset(bp, gr_bmi==j & year==k))
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I couldn't find that ^^;;;;